# mutt html-attachments

Tags: firefox, mutt

jCalling up mails containing a html-attachment with 'v' and
clicking on the attachment (to be read with Mozilla Firefox), I get:

```
Problem loading page 
File not found
Firefox can’t find the file at /tmp/mutt.html.
```

Saving the attachment as (e.g.) 'z.html', the file can easily be called up with Firefox.
Oddly enough, if I leave this file in the firefox window,
for any html-attachments in further mails, the procedure 'call up with "v" and click on the attachment' seems
to work in (almost) every case but, as soon as I close
the first window, the 'Problem loading page' reappears. 
Any suggestions?

---

Here is my .muttrc :

```
# Header
ignore *
unignore Date From To Subject
#colors
color hdrdefault blue white
#color quoted green black
#color signature red black
#color header green white ^From:
color header red default ^From:
#color header brightblue white ^Subject:
color header red default ^Subject:
color indicator brightgreen blue
color attachment brightmagenta black
color error brightred black
color status brightgreen blue
color tree brightgreen black
color normal brightblack default
##############
#neueste Mail wird als letzte angezeigt:
set sort=date-received
#alternativ:
#set sort=reverse-date-received
set status_on_top = yes
set print = ask-yes
#
# Drucken
#
#set print_command = "lp -c -dg -oD"
# set print_command = "rm -f heino.ps; a2ps -1 > heino.ps" 
#
# Folder
set folder = "~/Mail"
#
# set record = "~/Mail/sent"
# set mbox = "~/Mail/inbox"
set mbox = "~/Mail/1und1"
#
# verwendeter Editor
#
set editor = vim
set realname = "Gerd Heinlein"
my_hdr From: gheinlein@online.de
my_hdr Reply-To: gheinlein@online.de
#
# Nachrichten in der Testphase nicht vom Server löschen
# set delete=no
# Teilt den Bildschirm in die Anzeige von 'Mail' und 'Pager'
set pager_index_lines=1

# Mail that belongs together should be displayed in a thread-tree:
set sort = threads

# Scrolling line by line in index mode
set menu_scroll = yes

set locale = "de_DE.UTF-8"
set charset = "UTF-8"
set charset = "ISO-8859-15"

# aliases
#source $HOME/.aliases
#
set wrap_search = no
set help = no
set copy = no
set move = no
# pop account @1und1.de

set pop_host = pop.1und1.de
set pop_pass = "xxxxxxxxx"
set pop_user = gheinlein@online.de
set pop_delete
set pop_checkinterval = 300

# Vom lokalen Mailserver (sendmail) zu msmtp umleiten
set sendmail = "/usr/bin/msmtp"

## Makros ##
# Fetchmail mit 'G' aus mutt heraus aufrufen
macro index G "!fetchmail -K -m 'procmail -d %T'\r"
macro pager G "!fetchmail -K -m 'procmail -d %T'\r"

set mail_check
set check_new
set beep_new

set print = ask-yes
```

---

My mailcap file by far exceeds the limit of 30000 characters. I suppose that
most lines in that file are irrelevant here and could be parsed for this post (like entries containing 'opendocument' or 'video'), but I really don't know which ones I should keep. ???

Comment: Is this helping? https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/445566/224687

Comment: Thanks, but no - the problem persists although I added "text/html; firefox %s; copiousoutput;" to my mailcap.

Comment: I think it would help if you post your `.muttrc` and `mailcap` file.

Comment: I have these files (4K and 60K, respectively) ready for posting, but I don't know where to send them. (Is there an e-mail address for 'ploth' ?)

Comment: Add the content to your question

Comment: I still don't know which parts of my mailcap file I should post (the file in its entirety being too large to be added to the question). G.Heinlein

Comment: So you copied it from somewhere probably? Then send the link at least or post the lines mentioning fieefox.

Comment: Here are the first 6 lines mentioning 'firefox' (from my own file '/etc/mailcap') - altogether there are 16 lines, exceeding the limit on the number of characters:            text/html; firefox -private-window %s; test=test -n "$DISPLAY"
text/html; firefox %s; copiousoutput;
text/xml; firefox -private-window %s; test=test -n "$DISPLAY"
application/xhtml+xml; firefox -private-window %s; test=test -n "$DISPLAY"
application/xml; firefox -private-window %s; test=test -n "$DISPLAY"
application/rss+xml; firefox -private-window %s; test=test -n "$DISPLAY"

Comment: The next 8 lines:        application/rdf+xml; firefox -private-window %s; test=test -n "$DISPLAY"
image/gif; firefox -private-window %s; test=test -n "$DISPLAY"
image/jpeg; firefox -private-window %s; test=test -n "$DISPLAY"
image/png; firefox -private-window %s; test=test -n "$DISPLAY"
x-scheme-handler/http; firefox -private-window %s; test=test -n "$DISPLAY"
x-scheme-handler/https; firefox -private-window %s; test=test -n "$DISPLAY"
x-scheme-handler/ftp; firefox -private-window %s; test=test -n "$DISPLAY"
x-scheme-handler/chrome; firefox -private-window %s; test=test -n "$DISPLAY"

Comment: The last 2 lines mentioning 'firefox':          video/webm; firefox -private-window %s; test=test -n "$DISPLAY"
application/x-xpinstall; firefox -private-window %s; test=test -n "$DISPLAY"

Comment: It just ocurred to me that the line                   x-scheme-handler/chrome; firefox -private-window %s; test=test -n "$DISPLAY"   could/should be deleted - I removed 'chromium' from my computer some time ago.  ???